# Legend properties for a raster: how to get rid off one value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, symbology, legend

I have a raster in ArcMap, which has the values 0,1 (it was derived from Raster Calculator)
I want to put in the Legend only the value 1. I put no color and no line to value 0, but I have this big gap between the Layer name and the label (see the following picture). 
How can I get rid off the value 0, in order to have a nice looking legend?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open the properties of the Raster, go to Symbology and Select the "Unique Values" option of the left hand side of form.

In this new option you can select the values you want removed from the Layer Display (and thus your legend).